# Create an array from xml file

Tags: php, xml, arrays, phpunit

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <Post>
      <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
      <title><![CDATA[The title]]></title>
      <body><![CDATA[This is the post body.]]></body>
      <created><![CDATA[2008-07-28 12:01:06]]></created>
      <modified><![CDATA[]]></modified>
    </Post>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Post>
      <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
      <title><![CDATA[A title once again]]></title>
      <body><![CDATA[And the post body follows.]]></body>
      <created><![CDATA[2008-07-28 12:01:06]]></created>
      <modified><![CDATA[]]></modified>
      <item>
        <item><![CDATA[fdgs]]></item>
      </item>
    </Post>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Post>
      <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
      <title><![CDATA[Title strikes back]]></title>
      <body><![CDATA[This is really exciting Not.]]></body>
      <created><![CDATA[2008-07-28 12:01:06]]></created>
      <modified><![CDATA[]]></modified>
    </Post>
  </item>
</root>
```

Here is the my expected output:

```
Array(
0=>Array(
    'Post'=>Array(
        'id'=>1, 
        'title'=>'The title', 
        'body'=>'This is the post body.', 
        'created'=>'2008-07-28 12:01:06', 
        'modified'=>'',)
        ), 
1=>Array(
    'Post'=>Array(
        'id'=>2, 
        'title'=>'A title once again', 
        'body'=>'And the post body follows.', 
        'created'=>'2008-07-28 12:01:06', 
        'modified'=>'', 
        array('fdgs'),)
        ), 
2=>Array(
    'Post'=>Array(
        'id'=>3, 
        'title'=>'Title strikes back', 
        'body'=>'This is really exciting Not.', 
        'created'=>'2008-07-28 12:01:06', 
        'modified'=>'',)
        ),
);
```

And this is my code:

```
$xml=new Xml2Array();
        $xmlData = simplexml_load_file('d:\\xmlfile\\Array2XmlExampleData.xml');
        $expectedResult=$xml->simpleXMLToArray($xmlData);
        var_dump($expectedResult);
```

The array result I get from var_dump() is null.
How can I solve this problem? Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show the relevant which is the `simpleXMLToArray()` function. So we can't really tell what's wrong with your code.

But converting a SimpleXML-Object into an array is actually not that hard - here's one way to do it:

```
$array = json_decode( json_encode( (array) $xmlData ), true);
```

converts a given XML to an array. But to make it work in your case you need to make sure you load your data with the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag ([see documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)):

`$xmlData = simplexml_load_file('d:\\xmlfile\\Array2XmlExampleData.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`

Now you just load your XML, iterate through the `<item>`-tags and convert them to arrays:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file(
      'd:\\xmlfile\\Array2XmlExampleData.xml', 
      'SimpleXMLElement', 
      LIBXML_NOCDATA
);

$results = [];

foreach($xmlData->item as $item)
{
  $results[] = json_decode(json_encode((array)$item), true);
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Tdg4na). Of course you'll need to add your sanitization logic to filter the unwanted elements or do some formatting. But you get the idea.

Also, make sure the xml is loaded properly and that your application has reading permissions for the file.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks but the main problem in my function is here 
There is a condition if (!($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement))
which returns bool(FALSE) if I check that using var_dump(get_class($xml)); It returns SimpleXMLElement.

So, How can this possible???

Comment: @user2715247 It's hard to tell without seeing the whole code. You can edit your post and add the code of the `simpleXMLToArray()` function and tell what exactly you are tyring to achieve (why would you need to check the type...?). `if ( ! ($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) )` evaluates to `false` because you're actually checking if $xml is **NOT** instance of SimpleXMLElement. So if it's true, you return NOT True, which is false. It works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hNOB30